# How to keep running c++ code after popen?

Tags: c++, console, pipe, gnuplot, popen

I am studying numerical analysis subject and trying to make code using c++.

What I want to make is following,
At first, I want to call gnuplot program and plot the function. But I did it by using popen function.

And then, I see the plotted graph and put a value to calculate solution of problem simultaneously.(I failed.)

The problem is that the program doesn't keep running after opening gnuplot program.

How can I keep running c++ code after using popen?

This is the code I made

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

//const char func1[30] = "(10*x)*sin(x*100)";

void plotFunction(char function[50], double x_min, double x_max);

char func1[30] = "sin(3*x)";
char func2[50] = "sinh(x)";

int main()
{
    
    plotFunction(func1, 0.0, 6.3);
    plotFunction(func2, -3, 3);
    cout << "process finished" << endl;

    return 0;
}


void plotFunction(char function[50], double x_min, double x_max)
{
    char range[100];
    char min[10]; char max[10];
    sprintf(min, "%f", x_min);
    sprintf(max, "%f", x_max);
    strcpy(range, "set xrange [");
    strcat(range, min);
    strcat(range, ":");
    strcat(range, max);
    strcat(range, "]\n");
    
    char plot[200];
    strcpy(plot, "plot ");
    strcat(plot, function);
    strcat(plot, "\n");
    

    FILE* plotHandle = NULL;

    if (plotHandle == NULL) {
        plotHandle = _popen("C:\\Program\" \"Files\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot.exe -continue", "w");
        assert(plotHandle != NULL);
    }

    fprintf(plotHandle, "set terminal wxt\n");
    fprintf(plotHandle, "set xlabel \"X\"\n");
    fprintf(plotHandle, "set ylabel \"Y\"\n");
    fprintf(plotHandle, range);
    fprintf(plotHandle, "set grid\n");
    fprintf(plotHandle, "plot (10*x)*sin(x*100)\n");
    fprintf(plotHandle, plot);
    //fflush(plotHandle);

    //_pclose(plotHandle);

}
```

Comment: I think your program is blocking and waiting for the sub process you launched to exit. Try it with something simpler that you know will terminate. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/popen.html to verify.

Comment: If you change '-continue' to '-persist', what would happen?